# Cannot create 2 line in same chart in node-red

Tags: javascript, node-red

In node-red.I want to create control chart to have upper and lower line in same chart but I can't do java script in function node to call the line to show.
I don't know if the java incorrect.

[image: This is a java script I create but the line not appear]

```js
var textData = {};
var textData1 = {};
textData.series = ['Upper', 'Lower'];
msg.topic = ['msg.Upper'];
msg.topic = ['msg.Lower'];
msg.payload = textData;
msg.payload = textData1;
textData.data = [
    ['msg.Upper'],
    ['msg.Lower']
];
return { payload: [textData, textData1] }
```

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of text/code, paste the actual text and use the toolbar to format it. Images are hard to read, impossible for those that use screen readers and not searchable.

Comment: FYI: Java != JavaScript. Also, do not create intermediate variables in JavaScript like that. Just build one nested structure.

Comment: Where is `msg` defined? I see a `return`, so is `msg` a parameter of the function in this scope? Also, you reassigned the `topic` and `payload` with two subsequent calls.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl all that code runs in a sandbox and the `msg` object is injected into the scope.. Documentation for handling charts is here https://github.com/node-red/node-red-dashboard/blob/master/Charts.md

Answer (score 0):

You should be outputing 2 messages, one for each series.

So assuming you have 2 Text Input's for the values, you want 2 function nodes attached to the outputs of the relevant Text Input as follows, then these should be wired to the chart node.

```
msg.topic = 'Upper'
return msg
```

and

```
msg.topic = 'Lower'
return msg
```

Or you could just set the topics in the config of the Text Input nodes and do away with the function nodes all together.

Comment: I ever do like this but 2 line does not start in same time. I want upper line and lower line start at same time, so I use 1 function node but the line doesn't appear.

Comment: This is first time for me to do java script 

Comment: Read the doc on how to properly send multiple messages from a function node https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/writing-functions#multiple-messages